# Simple question. I know the answer but do not how to make a good steps.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The two person at different level in a building.

"A" at level 107. "B" at level 62. "A" can move down 4 level at one time and "B" can move up 3 level at one time. So, the question is at what level both of them will meet.

The formula i manage to create is

107 - 4a = 62 +3b

when i manually calculate (use picture and move them one by one) i got they will meet at 83 where "A" move 6 times and "B" move 7 times.

How to get the answer 83 using mathematical way not using my way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a typo in your text, to get that solution A has to move 6 times and B 7

Comment: owh thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us work with modulo.
We have $107 \mod 4 = 3$, so they meet only when $62 +3b \mod 4 =3$, which gives use $b = 3 +4 m$, and since $62 + 3b \le 107$, we find $b \in \{ 3,7,11,15\}$.
So let us consider those cases

$b=3$ Then we have $B$ at $71$, and $107-71=36$ which is divisible by $4$, so floor $71$ is possible.
  $b=7$ Then we have $B$ at $83$, and $107-83=24$, so floor $83$ is possible.
  $b=11$ Then we have $B$ at $95$, and $107-95=12$, so floor $95$ is possible.
  $b=15$ Then we have $B$ at $107$, so floor $107$ is possible.

Comment: owh ok. understood thank a lot.

Comment: And if you don't feel like checking each case, notice that when one case holds, the others most also holds, as the difference is $12$ floors between each case, so $A$ has to move $3$ times less each case.